# Is it wrong to insert elements using text and .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools

I have some javascript that looks like this:

```
var sel = '<option value="{value}" {selected}>{name}</option>';
...
$(index + '_expiry').innerHTML = sel; // $(index + '_expiry) is a select.
```

This works fine in firefox, but not in Internet Explorer - not even IE9.

[There is already a solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364748/change-the-options-array-of-a-select-list) that involves creating new elements in the DOM rather than changing the innerHTML.

Is it wrong to insert new elements into a page by manipulating `.innerHTML`? I use the `innerHTML` approach all over my site and it is easy. It works in IE for simple elements like `.div` too.

Though `IE` is often annoying to work with, the newer versions have a stricter javascript parser that is probably more correct - for instance, it doesn't like an array created as `['a','b','c',]`.

So, is it bad, inefficient, unreliable, or similar to use `.innerHTML` to create new HTML elements in the DOM? Should I use it for only inserting plain text? Or is this just IE benig stubborn?

Comment: `the newer versions have a stricter javascript parser that is probably more correct - for instance, it doesn't like an array created as ['a','b','c',]` Actually that's explicitly _incorrect_; `[ECMA-262: A.3]` allows the trailing comma.

Comment: I would love to see this moved over to the programming stackexchange... I've been wondering this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is it bad

Subjective

> inefficient

Usually more efficient then the alternatives in terms of run time. The cost comes from making sure the strings are properly constructed.

> unreliable

Browsers are consistent (although not always with other browsers), so you can rely on decently tested code.

> Or is this just IE benig stubborn?

IE doesn't like editing the insides of certain elements (tables and select elements in particular).

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery and not using it *at the same time*. Just use jQuery:

```
$(index + '_expiry').html('<option value="{value}" {selected}>{name}</option>');
```

Comment: Once again demonstrating why `$` is not a [good variable/function name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting).

Comment: @Quentin I thought about including the 'mootools' tag, but it wasn't really relevant to the main thrust of the question, so I didn't.

Comment: @Quentin That's why we have question tags and don't answer questions based on unverified assumptions.

Comment: @Oliver: Then you should have abstracted it away and replaced its usage with that of `document.getElementById`

Comment: @Blender Library differences aside, does JQuery's `.html` method solve this problem for IE?

Comment: @Oliver What jQuery would do here is make the code that constructs a DOM fragment and inserts that into the <select> as clear as using `.html()`: http://jsfiddle.net/zkT2R/ (Both of those seem to work for me in IE9 though.)

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is perfectly fine if your code is actually correct. The point of using DOM manipulation is that it's impossible to create badly formed HTML because of a typo or because, say, the value of whatever goes into the `{name}` placeholder contains HTML syntax. It's considered better because it helps prevent bugs – this is probably a wash when you're generating chunks of HTML as small as one simple tag.