# Updating select options after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2, jquery-select2

I have select field looking like that:

```
<?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]id")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(PresentationPlace::find()->all(), 'id', 'displaynew'),
    'class' => 'field',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Pick place for presentation')],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => false
    ],
])->label(Yii::t('app', Yii::t('app', 'Place'))) ?>
```

And after that field, I have short form for adding new place - you can fill it and send AJAX request. It adds this place to my database. I would like to have my select options updated, after the AJAX request is complete - that options would be up-to-date after every new place added. How can I achieve that in Yii 2?

Comment: You should find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364748/change-the-options-array-of-a-select-list

Comment: @Oliver unfortunetely I can't find any answer for my problem there. I suppose Yii doesn't allow me to add select options in so simple way.

Comment: When you select from the list you need to send ajax request? Is that what you mean by your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yii 2 is a PHP framework and thus operates on the server side. You have to change the options in the select on the client side. Looking at the tags of your question, I assume that you are using jQuery. This is how you can update the options in a select, given an array of options. I will assume that you get something along those lines via an AJAX call. If your AJAX call returns JSON, you can get an object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

**jQuery**

```js
var options = {
      apple: 'Apple',
      banana: 'Banana',
      pear: 'Pear'
    },
    $select = $('select');

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $select.find('option').remove();
  $.each(options, function(value, name) {
    $select.append($('<option />', {value: value, text: name}));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
<button>Change options</button>
```

If you are using [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) then do not forget to call `$select.trigger('change')` after you have updated the options. This will update the dropdown. In case you are not using jQuery at all, you can use the below code.

**vanilla JavaScript**

```js
var options = {
      apple: 'Apple',
      banana: 'Banana',
      pear: 'Pear'
    },
    select = document.querySelector('select');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // remove current options
  while (select.firstChild) {
    select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
  }
  
  // insert new ones
  Object.keys(options).forEach(function(value) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('value', value);
    option.innerHTML = options[value];
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>
<button>Change options</button>
```

On the server side, you only need to be sure to [query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) your database for the options that have been stored there and pass that as the `options` instead of the placeholder that you have there now.

Hope that helps.